# Angular 10 and threex.domevents.js

Tags: angular, three.js

I m having a problem using threex in angular, someone know how to use this js library in angular?

Comment: Please let us what you have tried so far and where you are facing problems.

Answer (score 0):

I alredy have tried to import the library through npm and also as an external .js but i cant use the variable THREEx inside the js in a component.ts